# How do you apply round-trip delay when syncing a clock with NTP

Tags: ntp

The [wikipedia page for NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) says two calculations are necessary it to sync a clock:

1. offset
2. round-trip delay

Applying the offset to the client clock makes sense, but how does the round-trip delay come into play? I've made it all the way to the [RFC for NTP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc958) and still can't figure it out.

From what I can tell, you only need to apply the offset to the client clock at its current time to bring it in sync.

You could use the round-trip delay by dividing it by two and adding it to the offset and applying that number the initial client clock time (I think). But, I'm not sure what that gets you over applying the offset directly.

Can you get by with just the offset, or is the round-trip delay involved in the calculation in a direct way?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot get by with just the offset--the round-trip delay is involved in the calculation in a direct way, as shown below (see [https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/time.html](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/%7Emills/time.html)).

Basically (there is a bit more to it), NTP *estimates* these as follows:

```
offset = ((T2 - T1) + (T3 - T4))/2
delay = (T4 - T1) - (T3 - T2)


-where:

T1 = client timestamp at time of departure of request packet from client

T2 = server timestamp at time of ARRIVAL of request packet at server

T3 = server timestamp at time of departure of REPLY packet from server

T4 = client timestamp at time of ARRIVAL of REPLY packet back at client
```